# Listing Elements of JSON Array with v-for

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js, v-for

I have an API containing my Data in JSON format. It successfully loads and i can display the array as a whole, but i'm having issues displaying certain fields.

The array is stored in a field:

```
           peoples: '',
           errors: ''
```

This is how i'm currently trying to display the info

```
  <div id="table">
   <li v-for="people in peoples">
       {{people}}
   </li>
```

Whis displays it as :

```
{ "username": "example", "firstnames": "ex", "middle": "NULL", "surname": "example", "email": "example@example.com", "picture": "", "title": "NULL", "active": 1 } 
{ "username": "example", "firstnames": "ex", "middle": "NULL", "surname": "example", "email": "example@example.com", "picture": "", "title": "NULL", "active": 1 } 
{ "username": "example", "firstnames": "ex", "middle": "NULL", "surname": "example", "email": "example@example.com", "picture": "", "title": "NULL", "active": 1 } 
{ "username": "example", "firstnames": "ex", "middle": "NULL", "surname": "example", "email": "example@example.com", "picture": "", "title": "NULL", "active": 1 } 
{ "username": "example", "firstnames": "ex", "middle": "NULL", "surname": "example", "email": "example@example.com", "picture": "", "title": "NULL", "active": 1 }
```

I know that putting {{people[0}.username} displays the value, but thats only for a single record, how can i do it so that it lists all usernames(regardless of array size etc)

eg)

```
username123
username124
username125
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added .data to this.peoples

```
.then(response => {
 console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data))
 this.peoples = response.data.data
 })
```

change peoples:'' to peoples:[]

```
export default {
data(){
    return{
        peoples: [],
        errors: ''
    }
},
```

And finally:

```
      <li v-for="people in peoples">
      {{people.username}}
      {{people.firstnames}}
      </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is correct:

```
<div id="table">
<li v-for="people in peoples">
 {{people.username}}
 {{people.firstnames}}
</li>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, this results in the same way as mentioned below, with a blank page

Comment: what would output {{ peoples }} ?

Comment: @marcogomes the difference between putting
{{people}} and {{peoples}}

{{peoples}} = { "data": [ { "username": "example", "firstnames":"example".........}
{{people}} =  [ { "username": "example", "firstnames":"example".........}

Comment: create data: () => ({ peoples: [] }), faz a requisição, e atribui a resposta no this.peoples. this.peoples = response.data

Comment: @Tom could you show how do you assing `peoples`? It looks like exact response object, `peoples` should be actual `peoples.data`

Comment: @HamiltonGabriel my request is already like this, it's

            .then(response => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data))
                this.peoples = response.data
            })

Comment: @barbsan Thanks! changed it to 

  <div id="table">
      <li v-for="people in peoples.data">
          {{people.username}}
          {{people.firstnames}}
      </li>
  </div>

And it works.

Comment: @Tom but it's not how it should be done... I didn't mean to replace in template `peoples` with `peoples.data` but in place where you assign its value

Comment: response.data.data = this.peoples

Comment: @barbsan oh i see, i set peoples to peoples:[] and set this.peoples to response.data.data and this fixed it without needing to have peoples.data in the template section.